# symfony2: generate form, single field, redirect to url with submitted input

Tags: forms, symfony

What I want to do is pretty simple:

1) A single input box with a submit button
2) I want to take whatever input and redirect the user based on the input, so if my site is www.example.com and the user submits 'test' then I want to redirect to www.example.com/test

However, the symfony2 docs are lacking in examples.   I have been able to build my form with this:

```
class VariantType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
            $builder
            ->add('urlId', 'text', array('label' => 'tiny.cc/'))
            ->add('Go', 'submit')
            ->getForm();
  }  

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'index';
  }

}
```

This generates things fine, but I realize I have no submission handler.  I assume I need a 'newAction function which takes the request as explained in different parts of the documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

So I tried this....

```
 public function newAction(Request $request){

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage_id'));
    }


  }
```

My 'homepage_id' route handles the route with the 'test' input on the end of the url.  I think I can just forward to the url I want and my routing system will handle everything, which shows you how basic my needs are.  But the above doesn't seem to work. I also have a validation.yml, but I don't think this is my real hurdle.  Even if anyone can point to any docs which explain something like this I would appreciate it.  (The symfony2 docs are just not helpful: it tells me creating a formbuilder is recommended, but doesn't say how to submit the form, so I go to the section where it talks about submitting the form, and try and put in the relevant function, but still doesn't work.  I can't find any example which puts these pieces together.)

Comment: `But the above doesn't seem to work` - what errors did you get ?

Comment: no errors, it just doesn't reroute.  Well not to the correct path.  It goes to www.example.com/#  So it appends the '#'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Routing placeholders](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-with-placeholders) to handle your redirection based on user input.

Define your `homepage_id` route :

```
homepage_id:
path:      /{slug}
defaults:  { _controller: YourBundle:YourController:yourAction }
```

In your action, redirect to the above route like this:

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('homepage_id',
        array('slug' => $form->getData()->yourFIeldGetter())
    );
```

Comment: Actually, the problem isn't the route, it's that I want a **FORM** that takes input for the url that and redirects to that url.  It's the form sumbmission that I'm not sure how to get working.

Comment: Ok, this does help some. However, it appears, if I place this code in the newAction codeblock and then try and run my debugger (or with print statements), the submission of the form never even goes into this function newAction.  I think I'm missing a step, but the docs are all over the place it's hard to find out how to get this newAction to work.

Comment: Ok I think I found out the general procedure.  Your suggestion did help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using a form template, as above, the handling of the form can be done in your controller. (Usually found under something like Controller/DefaultController.php).  This is where your actions would be defined.  The confusion is that when using a form template means I created a file in the form namespace under a different filename (Form/MyType.php).  If you do this, then you can still deal with your form handling in DefaultController.php

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Then you can do something like this:

```
if ($isInvalidUrlId) {
  if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
      // get form data
      $data = $form->getData();

      //if urlid exists in the database redirect to that url
      $checkurlqb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
      $isInvalidUrlId = self::checkUrlId($data->getUrlId(), $checkurlqb);
      //if is invalid redirect to general page
      if ($isInvalidUrlId) {
        $url = $this->generateUrl('homepage_id');
      }
      // if is not invalid, re
      else {
        $url = $this->generateUrl('homepage_id', array('id' => $data->getUrlId()));
      }

      return $this->redirect($url);
    }
  }
}
```